# In a nested loop, should Parallel.For be used on the outer or inner loop?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, task-parallel-library

I'm shifting some code from .NET 2 to 4 and making use of TPL among other things.

Although I'm sure this question must have been asked somewhere on SO, I could not find it.

I know that over-nesting TPL tasks can be detrimental to performance.

```
for (int y=0; y < h; y++)
    for (int x=0; x < w; x++)
        grid [x, y] = ((x + 1) * (y + 1));
```

Would you substitute the outer or inner loop above to TPL and why? And what if there were an additional level of nesting?

Here is the code with the inner loop replaced which fared better in my case by as much as 1 second.

```
int w = 10000;
int h = 10000;
int [,] grid = new int [w, h];
int [] index = new int [w * h];
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();

options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;

time = DateTime.Now;
for (int y=0; y < h; y++)
{
    Parallel.For
    (
        0,
        w,
        options,
        x =>
        {
            grid [x, y] = ((x + 1) * (y + 1));
        }
    );
}
span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time);
Console.WriteLine("Filled in " + span.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds.");

time = DateTime.Now;
for (int y=0; y < h; y++)
{
    Parallel.For
    (
        0,
        w,
        options,
        (x, state) =>
        {
            if (grid [x, y] < index.Length)
            {
                index [grid [x, y]]++;
            }
            else
            {
                state.Break();
            }
        }
    );
}
span = DateTime.Now.Subtract(time);
Console.WriteLine("Indexed in " + span.TotalSeconds.ToString() + " seconds.");
```

Comment: Relevant thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807330/nested-parallel-for-loops-speed-and-performance

Comment: @svick: I haven't profiled but timing through code came out with 3.5 seconds by replacing the outer loop and 2.6 seconds for the inner loop.

Comment: @RaheelKhan In that case, could you show us a minimal code sample that reproduces your measurements? Especially important are the values of `w` and `h`.

Comment: @svick: Full code added above with inner loop as parallel.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Don't measure execution time with `DateTime`, use `StopWatch` instead, it's much more accurate.

Comment: @svick: Sure, but in this case the difference was as much as a second apart so granularity is not an issue.

Comment: @RaheelKhan I get different results, parallelizing the inner loop gives me 0.8/3.5s, and outer loop gives 0.5/3.3s, so parallelizing outer loop seems to be clearly faster.

Comment: Also, I get even better results by parallelizing the outer loop, but having `x` in the outer loop and `y` in the inner.

Comment: @svick: Interesting. Not sure what to make of that since both loops have the same count.

Comment: @RaheelKhan My guess is that it has to do with memory layout and caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are seeing better performance when parallelizing the inner loop because `rect[x,]` is adjacent to `rect[x+1,]` in memory while `rect[,y]` is not adjacent to `rect[,y+1]`, so parallelizing the outer loop will cause more contention for the same memory space and slow things down.

That aside parrelleizing the outer loop should be faster, so more than likely if you switch the inner and outer loops and then do a `Parallel.For` on the outer loop you should get better performance than either of your current tests.

One other thing of note is that bounds checking is somewhat expensive, so you can also see some performance increase by using unsafe code/pointers instead of looping through large arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Outer loop, because using the inner one would cause much more cross thread communication than the outer one.

Comment: That's what I would have guessed but some initial tests showed: Outer: 3.5 seconds and Inner: 2.6 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

Neither!
Do you even have a performance problem? If the code sample you gave is real, it looks like you could benefit from a [jagged array](http://www.dotnetperls.com/jagged-array), who's performance is a lot better.

Comment: The grid is rectangular and trying it with the jagged array increased time.

Comment: That sounds odd. Jagged arrays give faster access to elements, although they take more time to allocate and burden the GC. Can you show the code you used? also note that in a jagged array, it is much more performnat to traverse it by columns, not by rows. This is related to the way they are stored in memory. If you would like I could elaborate more.

Comment: And its not cool to down-vote only because you feel the suggestion is wrong for you.

Comment: I did not vote down. In any case, the full code is posted above. You can easily replace it with jagged arrays and verify.

Comment: In case it helps, whoever voted down probably did so since the question was about TPL against conventional loops. The difference would be the same (relative) whichever kind of arrays were used.

Comment: The downvoter was right, you are wrong: jagged arrays are, if anything, *less* efficient than rectangular multi-dimensional arrays (due mainly to cache locality).