# Parallel For loop for Sum function performing poorly

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to implement the algorithm on Image below:

[image: Image of Algorithm]

My problem is, when I'm doing Sum in algorithm, it's taking so much time. Please, can you check, what am I doing wrong?

```
Parallel.For(0, n, i =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, n, j =>
    {
        double sum1 = 0;
        double sum2 = 0;
        if (i > j)
        {
            for (int a = 1; a < j - 1; a++)
            {
                sum1 = sum1 + (matrixL[i, a] * matrixU[a, j]);
            }

            matrixL[i, j] = (matrixA[i, j] - sum1) / matrixU[j, j];
        }
        else
        {
            for (int a = 1; a < i - 1; a++)
            {
                sum2 = sum2 + (matrixL[i, a] * matrixU[a, j]);
            }
            matrixU[i, j] = matrixA[i, j] - sum2;
        }
    });               
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a profiler?

Comment: The overhead from using Parallel.For might be too much for using it on both for loops. The pseudo code only specifies that the inner loop should be parallel

Comment: Can you give some context to what you consider to be _so much time_ and exactly what the size of your matrices are.

Comment: Also use Jagged arrays instead of multi-dimensional, those are optimized better by the CLR.

Comment: @MalteR That, with jagged arrays will also utilize the CPU cache better because every outer array will be accessed more consecutively.

Comment: How large is your Matrix?

Comment: Thank you for Answers/Questions. My matrix is variable. When I try 1000x1000 elements it takes 18oooms. I understand, when I use more and more elements, the Sum take more time for calc. I just want to know, if is there possible to make it more effective.

Comment: 18,000 ms = 18 seconds. Why is that unacceptable for your task? How long do you think that it *should* take (i.e. what would constitute an acceptable amount of time)?

Comment: Another thing: first, as @MalteR said, the pseudocode doesn't say to make the outer loop parallel. Secondly, it says that you're only supposed to loop until convergence, but I never see you test for that.

Comment: @EJoshuaS I not much understand, what mean "the pseudocode doesn't say to make the outer loop parallel" Can you more explain it?

Comment: @Oneteil The image you show says that only the inner loop is supposed to be parallel, the outer loop is an "ordinary" loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few items here.

First, as @MalteR indicated in the comments, the pseudocode doesn't say that the outer loop has to be parallel. I've read conflicting things about whether doing this is actually acceptable; [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/14/is-it-ok-to-use-nested-parallel-for-loops/) from Microsoft says that it's OK to have "nested" Parallel.For loops, but I've seen other Stack Overflow questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807330/nested-parallel-for-loops-speed-and-performance)) that have complained that doing so reduces performance.

To clarify, right now you have:

```
Parallel.For(0, n, i =>
{
    Parallel.For(0, n, j =>
    {
```

rather than

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Parallel.For(0, n, j =>
    {
```

Keep in mind that there's a hard limit to how much you can actually gain from parallelization. The machine can only do a finite number of things at once (let's call that *x*), so if you try to do more than *x* things at once for a CPU-bound task you won't actually improve performance.

You can experiment with that a little and look at the article I linked to to see if the outer Parallel.For loop is helping or hurting your performance.

The big optimization I see here is that the pseudocode specifically says that you only loop until convergence, but you always loop *n* times (even if it's not actually necessary). So you could do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Parallel.For(0, n, j =>
    {
      // Do the algo
    }

    if ([test for convergence]) {
       break; // No need to keep going
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for explain, I'm looking for that.

Comment: The pseudo code does have a regular loop for the outer and a parallel loop for the inner but I think the other way around would be faster.  You gain more from parallelism with fewer long iterations rather than more short iterations.  Of course there is a trade off point depending on the relative sizes.

Comment: I changed first step as you wrote, and now algorithm takes 2500ms for 1000x1000 elements.